# Dijkstra vs BellFord algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

If I need to find shortest paths from one source to all other vertices in graph, which is both directed and weighed, can I use Dijkstras algorithm or do I need to use BellFord algorithm?

Comment: Ford can handle negative weights, Dijkstra cannot. Use Ford when there are any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a proper implementation of Dijkstra is faster than Bellman-Ford, use Dijkstra unless there are negative weight edges in the graph. In this case Dijkstra can be incorrect, but Bellman-Ford will still return the correct answer.

Remember that if a graph has a negative weight cycle, then the shortest path is not well defined. Bellman-Ford can be modified to be able to check if a given graph has a negative weight cycle.